# I have an error With Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="update item_master set department=$dept,make=$make,vat=$vat,cost=$mrp,packing=$pack,unit=$unit,exp_date=$ex,stock=$stock,description=$desc
where item_code=$id";
mysql_select_db('pds', $conn);

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

And the error is :

> -id= 1dept=Ayurvedicmake=arihantname=sample2vat=4mrp=100pack=1*100Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where item_code= 1' at line 2

Comment: strings need to be quoted. and the error does not exactly match the code pasted, so make sure your looking at the right thing

Comment: After quoted the error is unexpected t_variable !

Comment: post exact new code, and exact error message

Comment: try item_code='$id'";

Comment: once again: 
 
post exact new code, and exact error message

Comment: $sql="update item_master set department=$dept,make=$make,vat=$vat,cost=$mrp,packing=$pack,unit=$unit,exp_date=$ex,stock=$stock,description=$desc
 WHERE item_code='$id'";

Comment: error :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_code=' 101'' at line 2

Comment: You don't need the $id variable to be quoted

Comment: Ok ,But Still Same Error !

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_code= 101 at line 2

Comment: Are you sure that your data that you plan on inserting into your database matches the data types of the columns in database?

Comment: Yes @HarshaKuchampudi

Comment: Try removing the ", $conn" from your select_db command and add it to your mysql_query

Comment: Where I remove quotes @Dagon?

Comment: inserted string values need them added not removed

Comment: It think there's no space between `$desc` and `where` . can you print the query and try running it on mysql ?

Comment: Yes There is space !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

Seeing that many of your variables stand at being strings, they are required to be quoted.

Another thing I spotted is that there is no space between `description=$desc` and `where`.

For example: If `$desc` is defined as `testing`, then MySQL is interpreting that as:

```
description=testingwhere item_code=$id
```

which will explain that error for a few reasons, an unquoted variable and the missing space.

Change your code to the following.

```
$sql="UPDATE item_master SET 
department = '$dept', make = '$make', vat = '$vat', cost = '$mrp', 
packing = $pack, unit = '$unit', exp_date= '$ex', stock = '$stock', 
description = '$desc' WHERE item_code=$id";
```

Sidenote: It's best using uppercase letters for functions and clauses. It helps to differentiate them from the rest of your code.

Plus, your code is highly prone to SQL injection. Consider using prepared statements, or sanitize your code for now, until you do.

Another important note.

If you're still having problems, then there may be characters being inserted that MySQL may be complaining about. Therefore, you will need to escape your data.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Example, and do the rest for the others:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($dept);
```

- Double check your column types so that it matches the data, and their lengths also.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: As of PHP 5.5.0 mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated

Comment: @vove yes I know that. I am merely pointing out to the OP instructions on what to use until they switch to another newer API. But OP's query is working but failing and the PHP version is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query

`$id` need to like `'$id'`

```
$sql="update item_master set department=$dept,make=$make,
vat=$vat,cost=$mrp,packing=$pack,unit=$unit,exp_date=$ex,
stock=$stock,description=$desc where item_code='$id'";
mysql_select_db('pds', $conn);

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```